# How to move blocks down to fill the gap after clearing a row in Tetris?

Tags: python, pygame, tetris

I'm working on a Tetris clone. When I clear a line, my code does this:

[image: Blocks floating above empty row]

I want to move the squares down + 1.

My code is:

```
verify_val = defaultdict(list)
    for val in grid:
        x, y = val
        if (x,y) in grid:
            if grid[(x,y)] != "white":
                verify_val[y].append(x)

    # list of rows
    compare_l = [x for x in range(x_left, x_right, 1)] 
    compare_l.sort()
    lines = 0
   
    pos = []
    change = False

    pos_n = []

    for y in verify_val:
        verify_val[y].sort()
        #compare if rows are full 
        if verify_val[y] == compare_l: # it was the rows, full
            lines += 1
            for x in verify_val[y]:
                pos.append((x,y))
            change = True
        else:
            if (x,y) not in pos_n:
                for x in verify_val[y]:
                    pos_n.append((x,y))


    if change:
        for x,y in pos_n:  
            grid[(x,y)] = grid[(x,y-1)]
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly what the problem is so that we can help. Does it not move correctly ? Or does it crash ? Or does it not move at all ? Does it freeze ?

Comment: The problem is i want the squares to move down n lines, but it shows like the picture. That white squares previous are pieces, and then I get a line, so I want to erase, and set new one to previous ones. For example in that picture I need to the squares go one down because I got one line clear.

Answer (score -2):

Well I got it, my problem is that I was doing operations on the same grid.

Comment: This answer would be better if you showed the code you changed and explained how that fixed the problem. Remember, the goal on this site is to leave answers that can help future users struggling with similar problems.